# PHP reading MySQL query results into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently running a MySQL query to return song titles from a database. Each song title returned displays on a different line when I `echo` the results. I would like to return the song titles as an array and then `echo` that array.

Example output:
songTitle1
songTitle2
songTitle3

What I am looking for:
Array
([1] => songTitle1 [2] => songTitle2) and so on

Thanks.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php

$varusername = $_POST['username'];

//connection string
$connection=mysqli_connect(<server_details>);

//check connection
if(!$connection)

{die("Failed to connect to MySql:".mysqli_connect_error());}

else
$query = "SELECT Title FROM songs WHERE Uusername='$varusername'";

$result = $connection->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row["Title"]. "<br>";
    }       
}

else

{die('SQL Error:'.mysqli_error($connection));}

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: do you have a sample of what you want to see?  That way I can help you load it

Comment: Put the example output in your question, not the comments.

Comment: I would like for it to look like this when I echo it back: Array( [1] => songTitle1 [2] => songTitle2 [3] => songTitle3)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `array` before the while loop runs and then use `array_push` to add each song item (or just the title) onto it. From there use `print_r($array)`, `var_dump($array)` or `json_encode($array)`to echo the array (as you cannot echo an array out directly).

Example code snippet:

```
$result = $connection->query($query);

$songsArray = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        array_push($songsArray, $row);
    }       
}

echo print_r($songsArray);
echo var_dump($songsArray);
echo json_encode($songsArray);
```